# Apache Camel schedule configuration not triggering

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am able to trigger my job using `delay` but I am not able to trigger using `schedule` parameter.

Here's my attempt (not triggering - I also tried to replace empty spaces for "+" and also tried to use `schedule` instead of `scheduler.cron`):

```
fromF("master:.../...:scheduler:MyJob?scheduler.cron=0/1 * * * *")
    .routeId("JobTimer")
    .toF("direct:%s", JOB_NAME)
    .end();
```

If I stop using `scheduler.cron` and start using the following uri, it works:

```
fromF("master:.../...:scheduler:MyJob?delay=...")
```

My version:

```
api group: 'org.apache.camel.springboot', name: 'camel-spring-boot', version: camelVersion
camelVersion = 3.9.0
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it's not triggering when using the 5 parts cron but I am able to trigger using 6 or 7 parts cron.

Triggering everyday at 8 AM for example: `0 0 8 * * ?`

Reference: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html#examples